# How to update a view prior to resume?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-view

**Background**

I have an Android app that displays the time as a string in a textview in the main activity. I update the text as each minute passes. When the power button is hit on my phone, the phone is locked and the app pauses (it is not destroyed). When the phone is unlocked, the app resumes, and things continue as normal.

**Problem**

After unlocking the phone, the app pops up and resumes, but initially, the time displayed in the textview is the time from when the app was locked. About a second later the time updates from me explicitly setting the time on resume.

```
override fun onResume() {
    // Try to make the clock update immediately
    clockView.text = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm").format(Date())
    super.onResume()
}
```

How do I update the textview prior to the old value being shown? Is android doing something funky like showing a snapshot of the app prior to properly resuming/rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try overriding the onStart, if Im not mistaken it is called before onResume and by then the app will not be shown to the user just yet.

```
override fun onStart() {
    clockView.text = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm").format(Date())
    super.onStart()
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention it in the original question, but I did try that lifecycle call too, plus a bunch of others (that weren't actually getting called). My issue was that I was setting the view text after calling `super.onStart()`, rather than calling it before. Your code helped me catch that error. Thanks!

Comment: I've just found that while this helps for when coming back from a locked screen, it isn't currently helping when I resume the app while using the phone. For example, hitting home when using the app to go to the default launcher, then coming back to the app a minute later (without it closing). I've confirmed onStart/onResume is still being called, but the clock textview takes a moment to update. So, you still see the old time first, then it updates. Any thoughts?

Comment: thats a lil tricky, why dont you just clear the text just before you pause the activity, that way when you return back to the activity, youll see a blank view for a second and then when onStart or onResume is called, you can set the text with the updated time.

clockView.text = "" can be done in onPause()

Comment: Ha, that's exactly what I've done! I just thought for sure I'd be able to update it before it displayed. But, clearly that's not the case. I can have a breakpoint in the onStart/onResume methods, then navigate to my app, and the app still loads even when I don't continue past the breakpoints. So, they are not blocking on the initial load. Which is good in general, just not for my use case, haha.

Comment: @Andrew well glad i could help (i think) lol :) Happy coding buddy!